# Javascript get variable into brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting some data from a url which looks like this:

```
{"654":{"name”:”…etc}
```

I have this data in a variable called `result`.

If I do this:

```
var mydata = [{"654":{"name”:”…etc}];
```

it works fine but if I do this:

```
var mydata = [+result+];
```

or

```
var mydata = [result];
```

I get error so my question is how do I get this to work so I can do:

```
var mydata = [ +mydatahere+ ];
```

?

Comment: *"I am getting some data from a url which looks like this"* Is it a *string*, or...?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: `var mydata = [result];` is the correct way of creating a new array with the value of `result` (if that's what you want to do). It's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to accomplish. *"get variable into brackets"* isn't a useful description. *"I get error"* And what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're receiving that information as a JSON string. If so, you need to parse it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
```

Example:

```js
// The JSON string
var result = '{"654":{"name":"foo"}}';

// Parse it
var data = JSON.parse(result);

// Use it
console.log(data[654].name);

// Use it in a loop
var key;
for (key in data) {
  console.log(key + " is ", data[key]);
}
```